# Push Notification not showing using parse sdk in Android 8.0

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am working on Android application where i have registered in FCM Push Notification in my custom Parse Push Notification class. When sending Push from Parse Dashboard, it is coming in my Receiver but not showing it in Notification Bar of my Screen. My Custom Class along with Manifest and code is given below. I have searched many similar question as well but no luck.

**My Manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.kolbeh" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
            android:value="id:854901#####" />

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="dinewhere.fcm.CustomPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**My Custom Receiver:**

```
public class CustomPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = CustomPushReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

    private Intent parseIntent;

    public CustomPushReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //super.onPushReceive(context, intent);

        if (intent == null)
            return;

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

            Log.e(TAG, "Push received: " + json);

            parseIntent = intent;

            parsePushJson(context, json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Push message json exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushDismiss(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushDismiss(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onPushOpen(context, intent);
        System.out.println("asdf");
    }

    /**
     * Parses the push notification json
     *
     * @param context
     * @param json
     */
    private void parsePushJson(Context context, JSONObject json) {
        try {
            String message = json.getString("alert");

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            resultIntent.putExtra("Chat", true);
            showNotificationMessage(context, "Hello", message, resultIntent);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Push message json exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    /**
     * Shows the notification message in the notification bar
     * If the app is in background, launches the app
     *
     * @param context
     * @param title
     * @param message
     * @param intent
     */
    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {

        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);

        intent.putExtras(parseIntent.getExtras());

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, intent);
    }
}
```

**My showNotificationMessage Method:**

```
 public void showNotificationMessage(String title, String message, Intent intent) {

        // Check for empty push message
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
            return;

        if (airportAssistUtil.isAppIsInBackground(mContext)) {
            // notification icon
            int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round;



            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            mContext,
                            0,
                            intent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                    );

            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    mContext);
            Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker("Kolbeh").setWhen(0)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                    .setContentTitle("Kolbeh")
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                    .setContentText(message)
                    .build();

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(count++, notification);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app targeting Android O. So you must show notification with notification Channel. From android O Each notification must contain inside a Channel [Read here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer here. Can you please give me an example of notification channel as per my code? I am little confuse in it.

Comment: If your app targeting Android O ? Then here is a [Example](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c) for exploring Android O Notification Channel . Please go through with it. And there is also a [Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NotificationChannels) from git.

Comment: Did you follow the sample i suggested ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helpful document. It really helped me alot. It is fixed. I was doing a mistake in initializing.